# How to search and replace text in all posts of a wordpress.com blog (NOT wordpress.org one)?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, search, text

I have some texts that need to be replaced in every posts in my blog. Is it possible to do that?

ps
(I need to tag this question as `search-and-replace` but not enough reputation to do that. Please add the tag if you can. Thank you!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least three different ways:

1) Edit directly in the database. The content of the post is stored in post_content column of wp_posts table. Since you are running your own WordPress, you should have full access to that. Just use [SQL to do search and replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace). Remember, the table content is sort-of HTML, so may have tags and/or escaped characters

2) Export your blog into XML, do search/replace in any UNICODE ready editor and import it back in after deleting original content. I would practice this a couple of times first though, especially checking what happens with images, etc.

3) Use [WordPress remote access API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp) to iterate through posts and update them that way. Good for programmers and/or more flexible way of doing things, such as content-specific updates.

Comment: In the title is specified that this is on WordPress.com, not a self-hosted blog, so your first suggestion won't work here. The XML-RPC way is interesting!

Comment: @Rafalovitch Your #2 suggestion: Deleting the original posts will make my blog lose the original created date of the post and I don't think I want to do that.

Comment: @Rafalovitch I'm a developer and love to try your #3 solution. Thank you!

Comment: @nam-gi-vu, I think if you export and import WordPress-specific XML format you can preserve the dates. It's been a while since I tested though. And of course, option 3 is more fun.

Answer (score 4):

Hi **@Nam Gi VU:**

I'm pretty sure that's not possible directly.

What you could do would be to export all posts to a text file, use a search and replace in a text editor and then import them back in deleting all the posts before you reimport them.  Be careful to change a copy of the export in case your search and replace corrupts the file and makes it fail to import.